# python selenium how to handle dynamic XPath within XPath 1.0

Tags: xpath, dynamic

I must select a field who's XPath is dynamic. In different sessions these are examples of XPath:

```
htmlb_335660_htmlb_115101_1
htmlb_323002_htmlb_110159_1
htmlb_331156_htmlb_111919_1
htmlb_335204_htmlb_114985_1
htmlb_324009_htmlb_110479_1
htmlb_331374_htmlb_111629_1
htmlb_331140_htmlb_112463_1
htmlb_324978_htmlb_110752_1
htmlb_324725_htmlb_110669_1
htmlb_336067_htmlb_115248_1
htmlb_324854_htmlb_110713_1
htmlb_334552_htmlb_112898_1
htmlb_415158_htmlb_142073_1
```

Here is the html code:

This are the only 3 code snippets I can use successfully to detect the fields:

```
ids = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'htmlb_') and contains(text(), 'htmlb_') and contains(text(), '_1')]")
ids = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(text(), 'htmlb_')]")
ids = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 1) = '_1']")
for ii in ids:
    print(">",ii)
```

All prints when I try to get an attribute ("id", "name", "title", "href", etc) give "attribute not found or "none". I suppose that starts-with works well and ends-with fail since ends-with is XPath 2.0 and most browsers neither Selenium supports it.

So I am "blindly" detecting 3 fields but I cannot see more details of the fields except when I print the object as above ("ii"): then I get:

```
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="a0779322-035d-41af-bb32-9c35973d3317", element="998d9583-79c8-4192-a078-c2d8719bbd9e")>
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="a0779322-035d-41af-bb32-9c35973d3317", element="25fa3805-7794-4760-b355-1ed408472e1d")>
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="a0779322-035d-41af-bb32-9c35973d3317", element="52f1ea41-3a27-4a62-8153-b38e31c1beaa")>
```

All this statements fail:

ids = browser. find_elements_by_id("id^='htmlb'")

ids = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[ends-with(text(), 'htmlb_')]")

ids = browser.find_elements_by_id('htmlb_'+ '\d{6}' + '*htmlb*' + '\d{6}' + '_1') <-- THIS ONE WOULD SOLVE MY PROBLEM!! WHY DOESN'T I WORK?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the HTML code got lost above:

```
<input type="text" class="urEdf2TxtEnbl" usedclasses="urEdf2TxtInv urEdf2TxtWarn urEdf2TxtRo urEdf2TxtRoInv urEdf2TxtRoWarn urEdf2TxtDsbl urEdf2TxtHlp" autocomplete="off" id="htmlb_425962_htmlb_146807_1" ct="I" name="htmlb_425962_htmlb_146807_1" st="" tp="STRING" f4always="false" tabindex="0" ti="0" title="Datoformat skal være dd-mm-åååå" value="04-07-2020" onchange="sapUrMapi_InputField_change('htmlb_425962_htmlb_146807_1',event);" onblur="sapUrMapi_InputField_Blur('htmlb_425962_htmlb_146807_1',event);" onkeydown="sapUrMapi_InputField_keydown('htmlb_425962_htmlb_146807_1',event);" onkeyup="sapUrMapi_InputField_KeyUp('htmlb_425962_htmlb_146807_1',event);" onfocus="sapUrMapi_InputField_focus('htmlb_425962_htmlb_146807_1',event);" onselectstart="sapUrMapi_InputField_onselectstart('htmlb_425962_htmlb_146807_1',event);" style="width:80px;" oldvalue="04-07-2020">
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a solution that returns me the object:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[substring(@id, 1, 6) = 'htmlb_' and substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 1) = '_1']")
```

However I have a frame problem and can't find the right object yet.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks. Two of your XPath expressions don't work with your sample data. The first :

```
//*[contains(text(), 'htmlb_') and contains(text(), 'htmlb_') and contains(text(), '_1')]
```

You have to specify you evaluate the `id` attribute, not the element. Note also the two different `htmlb` (position of the underscore).

```
//input[contains(@id, 'htmlb_') and contains(@id, '_htmlb') and contains(@id, '_1')]
```

The second :

```
//*[starts-with(text(), 'htmlb_')]
```

You have to specify you evaluate the `id` attribute, not the element :

```
//input[starts-with(@id, 'htmlb_')]
```

The third and the fourth XPath are perfectly fine though. So to sum up, you can use the following XPath (3 predicates) :

```
//input[starts-with(@id, 'htmlb_')][contains(@id, '_htmlb')][substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 1) = '_1']
```

or use this one with **translate** function :

```
//input[translate(@id,"0123456789","nnnnnnnnnn")="htmlb_nnnnnn_htmlb_nnnnnn_n"]
```

Generic code to use (frame support) to click on the element :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_to_the_frame")
driver.switch_to_frame(frame)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "one_of_the_preceding_xpath"))).click()
```

Side notes :
As you stated, Selenium doesn't support XPath 2.0 so you can't use  `function`.
AFAIK you can't use regex expression with a `find_elements_by_id` method.